# Calculate Positional Accuracy of Feature with CE/LE Values

Tags: accuracy

I would like to report the predicted positional accuracy of features that have been extracted from WorldView imagery. I have predicted horizontal accuracy and vertical accuracy values (CE90/LE90) for each point.

Is there an accepted method for reporting the overall CE/LE for a feature or set of features?

Can you simply use the max CE/LE, or is there a more rigorous method?

The only reference I've been able to find is this paper from ASPRS: http://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ASPRS_Positional_Accuracy_Standards_Edition1_Version100_November2014.pdf

It seems to be focused on sampled accuracy for raster products. It's not clear to me if it's relevant to predicted accuracy of vector features.